# Generics for Native Types (Primitives) in Java (or alternative approaches)

Tags: java, generics, primitive, built-in-types

I'm currently using two classes which both represent a data structure (sth like a special buffer, but to keep things simple in this example, lets just assume three fields) working on a native type; one is for `long`, the other for `float` (so both are working on native types).  To avoid code doubling, the straight approach would be to implement a generic on a type `<T>` and then have two users of this, once for `<long>` and once for `<float>`.

AFAIK this is not possible for native types; it only is possible for objects deriving from `Object`.

Is there any alternative approach to avoid the code doubling otherwise inevitable?  Using non-native types (like `Integer`) is not an option due to performance aspects.

The current code, stripped down to the minimal example of just having three fields:

```
public class TupleFloat {
  private float field1;
  private float field2;
  private float field3;
  public TupleFloat(float a, float b, float c) {
    field1 = a; field2 = b; field3 = c;
  }
  public float sum() {
    return field1 + field2 + field3;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class TupleLong {
  private long field1;
  private long field2;
  private long field3;
  public TupleLong(long a, long b, long c) {
    field1 = a; field2 = b; field3 = c;
  }
  public long sum() {
    return field1 + field2 + field3;
  }
}
```

Using generics:

```
public class Tuple<T> {
  private T field1;
  private T field2;
  private T field3;
  public Tuple<T>(T a, T b, T c) {
    field1 = a; field2 = b; field3 = c;
  }
  public T sum() {
    return field1 + field2 + field3;
  }
}
```

But this won't work for native types (`Tuple<float> x;`).

Is there any alternative approach to avoid the code doubling otherwise inevitable?  Is there maybe even a best-practice how to solve such an issue?

Comment: You can simply use the wrapper classes `Float`, `Integer`, `Long`, etc.

Comment: I just added the info that I need to stick to native types due to performance aspects.

Comment: No that's not possible as Generics are meant to work with Objects.

Comment: Would "something extends" `java.lang.Number` help?

Comment: What kind of operation are you doing on `Tuple` ?

Comment: In the example just summing it up.  In the original it's kind of a ring buffer which gets added to, emptied, zero'ed, summed up, averaged, …

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for primitives. Take a look at some of the built-in APIs, they are littered with various versions of methods for different primitives. You could theoretically have a single class with 6 private variables, and all the flavors, but that seems uglier than two separate "clean" classes.

You might be able to do something with Lambdas to handle this, but I'm not certain of that.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive numeric types cannot be used as arguments to generics (due to the way generics are defined). Also, you define `sum()`, so I'm not sure what you intend to do with types which are not "summable".

Yes, relying on autoboxing is expensive, that is an undeniable fact; and yes, primitives don't have object identity, so unlike in C# for instance you cannot have a `List<int>` (without even talking about type erasure).

This is why for Java 8, the implementation has defined, for instance, `IntStream` to "supplement" `Stream<Integer>`. In your case, that would mean defining `FloatTuple`, `IntTuple` etc.

Currently, there is no other way to do this in Java...